# Loop through Object of an array with Javascript

Tags: javascript

The bellow data are inside an array in JavaScript. How to display the value of each key?

```
[{
    "cities": [{
    "columnName": "Id"
  }, {
    "columnName": "Name"
  }, {
    "columnName": "Address"
  }, {
    "columnName": "Age"
  }]
}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `forEach()`

```js
var data = [{"cities":[{"columnName":"Id"},{"columnName":"Name"},{"columnName":"Address"},{"columnName":"Age"}]}]

data[0].cities.forEach(n => console.log(n.columnName))
```